# how to get back to the first index of matrices

Tags: matlab

I have to implement a single layer perceptron using Matlab.

The problem which I am facing is that when I ran my program it gave me output for every input (it shows results 4 times), but I want to go back to the first index of matrix, after when it reached to the fourth, and I can't find out that how I get back to the first index of matrix.

I want to train my program so that it yields the same result as in `b` by iterating the matrix in every loop.

This is my current code:

```
a = [ 1  1
      1 -1
     -1  1
     -1 -1 ];
b = [1
    -1
    -1
    -1];
disp(a);
disp(b);
x = a(:,1);
disp(x);
y = a(:,2);
disp(y)
learningrate = 0.1;
maxiteration = 10;
weight(1)=0.1;
weight(2)=0.1;
weight(3)=0.1;
count = length(x);
for p = 1:count
    s = (x(p) * weight(1))+ (y(p) * weight(2))+ weight(3);
    if s >= 0
        result = 1;
        if result ~= b(p)
            weight(1) = weight(1)+learningrate*(b(p)-result)*x(p);
            weight(2) = weight(2)+learningrate*(b(p)-result)*y(p);
            weight(3) = weight(3)+learningrate*(b(p)-result);
            disp(result);
            disp(x(p));
            disp(y(p));
            disp(weight(1));
            disp(weight(2));
            disp(weight(3));
         end   
    else
        if s <= 0
            result = -1;
            disp(result);
            if result ~= b(p)
                weight(1)=weight(1)+learningrate*(b(p)-result)*x(p);
                weight(2)=weight(2)+learningrate*(b(p)-result)*y(p);
                weight(3)=weight(3)+learningrate*(b(p)-result);
                disp(x(p));
                disp(y(p));
                disp(weight(1));
                disp(weight(2));
                disp(weight(3));
             end          
         end
     end
 end
```

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455660/matlab-single-layer-neural-network

Answer (score 1):

@Amro has posted an elaborate [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455660/matlab-single-layer-neural-network/3458036#3458036) on implementing a single layer perceptron with MATLAB. His post is not only valuable in terms of 'getting some code', but on how a technical problem shall be solved. It starts with a graphical representation of the perceptron showing the signal flow, the problem description. And goes on with excellent comments in the code, as part of the solution.

Just replacing variables `a` and `b` in your code with meaningful names could make a big difference.